# How would I implement nested Tab Bar Controllers in an IOS project

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitabbarcontroller

I"m trying to implement something like in the wireframe I basically want a Tab Nav Controller on the bottom, and then within on of the views, have another tab like controller. I'm just a little confused as to where I would start with this.

[image]

Comment: when you click on Tab1, On top you are set two button for toggle between two view? I'm right or not?

Comment: Yes that is the idea the buttons on top will toggle view on and view2

Answer (score 3):

I very much doubt there's a standard user control for that top tab-like control that you want. You may have to construct your own controller and view for that, then manually manage the center view when you get taps on your "View 1" and "View 2" labels.

Answer (score -1):

you should use not Tab Bar Controller, but Navigation Controller `toolbar` property. It looks like tab bar items but there's no need in implementation another controller instance.
Look at the [UINavigationController reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html)

> A navigation controller object manages an optional toolbar in its view
>   hierarchy. When displayed, this toolbar obtains its current set of
>   items from the toolbarItems property of the active view controller.
>   When the active view controller changes, the navigation controller
>   updates the toolbar items to match the new view controller, animating
>   the new items into position when appropriate.

This is some UIViewController class:

```
- (void)createToolbarItems
{
  UIImage *background = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2)];
  [self.navigationController.toolbar setBackgroundImage:background forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionBottom barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  self.navigationController.toolbar.delegate = self; // optional
  //... create some UIBarButtonItem items
  self.toolbarItems = @[item1, space, item2, space, item3, space, item4]; // we set items not to navigation controller instance, but the current controller
}

- (void)showToolbarAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
  if(!self.toolbar)
    return;
  [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```